# How to cover outside function in Jest test case React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using Jest for unit testing for my React Native project. I have created the test file and it's running successfully, but when I am checking the coverage some functions which are getting called inside the render() method are not covered. I have attached the image for that. How can I cover all these functions in my Jest file so my coverage will increase?

Below is test case:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import App from '../app/components/Home';
import DashboardContainer from '../app/components/container/DashboardContainer';
import MenuContainer from '../app/components/container/MenuContainer';
import DigitalFooter from '../app/components/ui/digitalFooter';
import OffersContainer from '../app/components/container/OffersContainer';
import DigitalSearchContainer from '../app/components/container/DigitalSearchContainer';
import BMobileDashboardContainer from '../app/components/container/BMobileDashboardContainer';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';


const defaultOptions = {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'ignore',
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      errorPolicy: 'all',
    },
  };
  
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: 'http://localhost:4000',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions
  })
  

  jest.useFakeTimers();

  
  test('Notification renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <MenuContainer />
          </ApolloProvider>
      ).toJSON();
    //console.log(tree);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('Homescreen Component renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <DashboardContainer/>
          </ApolloProvider>
      ).toJSON();
    //console.log(tree);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('Homescreen Component renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <BMobileDashboardContainer/>
          </ApolloProvider>
      ).toJSON();
    //console.log(tree);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  test('Homescreen Component renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <DigitalSearchContainer/>
          </ApolloProvider>
      ).toJSON();
    //console.log(tree);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

//   test('Login renders correctly', () => {
//     const tree = renderer.create(<DigitalFooter />).toJSON();
//     console.log(tree);
//     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
//   });

it('renders without error', () => {
    renderer.create(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <MockedProvider  addTypename={false}>
            <App/>
          </MockedProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  });
```

// Below is component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { getData, hasPermission } from './services/services';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
import DigitalFooter from './ui/digitalFooter';
import OffersContainer from '../components/container/OffersContainer';
import MenuContainer from '../components/container/MenuContainer';
import DashboardContainer from './container/DashboardContainer';
import DigitalSearchContainer from './container/DigitalSearchContainer';
import BMobileDashboardContainer from './container/BMobileDashboardContainer';
import parentStyle from '../themes/parent.style';
const APPLICATION_THEME = 'applicationTheme';
const APPLICATION_MODE = 'applicationMode';
const OPCO = 'opco';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeCount: 0,
      updateResponse: {},
      actionList: [],
      selectedTab: 'home',
      appliedTheme: '',
      appliedMode: '',
      showSearchScreen: false,
      opco: '',
      globalsearch: false,
      offers: false,
      tabs: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      appliedTheme: await getData(APPLICATION_THEME),
      appliedMode: await getData(APPLICATION_MODE),
      opco: await getData(OPCO),
      globalsearch: await hasPermission('dclm.fe.footer.globalsearch.allow'),
      offers: await hasPermission('dclm.fe.footer.offers.allow')
    });
    await this.prepareFooterTabs();
  }
  updateFooterColor = async() => {
    this.setState({
      appliedTheme: await getData(APPLICATION_THEME),
      appliedMode: await getData(APPLICATION_MODE),
    });
  }
  prepareFooterTabs = async () => {
    let tabs = [];
    const { globalsearch, offers } = this.state;
    const home = {
      page: 'home',
      iconText: 'Home',
      icon: 'ios-home',
      iconType: 'Ionicons',
    };
    const menu = {
      page: 'menu',
      iconText: 'Menu',
      icon: 'md-menu',
      iconType: 'Ionicons',
    };
    tabs.push(home);
   
    tabs.push(menu);
    this.setState({
      tabs: tabs
    })
  }

  selectFooterTab = (tab) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedTab: tab
    })
  }
  showSearchScreen = async (e) => {
    this.setState({
      showSearchScreen: e
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedTab, opco, tabs, appliedTheme, appliedMode } = this.state;
    const signatureHeadingColor = parentStyle[appliedTheme] ? parentStyle[appliedTheme][appliedMode].signatureHeadingColor : null;
    return (
      <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        {selectedTab === 'home' && opco === 'opco1_rose' && <BMobileDashboardContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} showSearchScreen={(e) => this.showSearchScreen(e)} />}
        {selectedTab === 'home' && opco === 'mauritius_telecom' && <BMobileDashboardContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} showSearchScreen={(e) => this.showSearchScreen(e)} />}
        {selectedTab === 'home' && opco === 'default' && <DashboardContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} showSearchScreen={(e) => this.showSearchScreen(e)} />}
        {selectedTab === 'search' && <DigitalSearchContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} showSearchScreen={(e) => this.showSearchScreen(e)} />}
        {selectedTab === 'offers' && <OffersContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} showSearchScreen={(e) => this.showSearchScreen(e)} />}
        {selectedTab === 'menu' && <MenuContainer navigation={this.props.navigation} selectedTab={selectedTab} updateFooterColor={()=> this.updateFooterColor()}/>}

        {this.state.tabs.length !== 0 && <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>
          <DigitalFooter
            signatureHeadingColor={signatureHeadingColor}
            tabs={tabs}
            screen={selectedTab}
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
            selectFooterTab={(tab) => this.selectFooterTab(tab)} />
        </View>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default withApollo(App);
```

Here red highlight is not covered in the test file:

[image]

Comment: Of course they're not fully tested, you never _interact_ with any of the components. And snapshot testing is just change detection, it doesn't even tell you if what's currently rendered is _correct_, try writing tests for actual _behaviour_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase test % in Jest React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092128/how-to-increase-test-in-jest-react-native)

Comment: @jonrsharpe getting confuse I am new to this.. could please help , could you please add one fucntion to my test case how I can map those  fucntions  just one example . Pelase . Like selectFooterTab()

Comment: It's not very complicated: if you want that function to get called, you need to simulate whatever action (clicking on one of the tabs?) on that component (which you didn't show) causes it to call the callback passed as that prop. But again this isn't a tutorial service, you need to read up on basic tutorials (I wrote one here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html).